# Dynamic Map Service with Zoom Slider in arcgis by API for javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and I want to show Zoom Slider by API 3.2 for javascript

Answer (score 3):

The ZoomSlider appears only when your map has a set of resolutions or LODs as they are called. If your map has a tiled layer then it automatically gets the LODs from that particular Map service.

If you want this ZoomSlider on a Map with contains only Dynamic Map services, you will have to set the LODs your self.

This samples shows how you can do so: [Set visible scales](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/map_customtilelevels)

Comment: ok i use lods from net but very zoom in to map . and when use map.tileInfo is undefind

Comment: @eman what do you mean? can you explain?

Comment: ok i mean zoom slider appear when set var lods =[level: 0, resolution: 0.3515625, scale: 230517.43451801158,level: 0, resolution: 0.3515625, scale: 230517.43451801158] as example but this zoom in my map what i do to get suitable lods

Comment: You need to figure that out based on your data, projection, the scale that you need. ect.

Comment: sorry can you give me example for this. you mean from my map get scale and use this in lods